# Automatically rename files on pull request completion

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration

I'm setting up a CI/CD process which needs to rename database scripts based on the timestamp of pull request completion (using TFS 2018 + Git).

Basically, I commit a file named `MS_01.sql` but I'd like to have it renamed to `20190101T100000_01.sql` upon completion of pull request.

I'm not very experienced in git hooks or TFS REST API, so any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: This is a weird requirement. Have you considered using a database scripting tool like SSDT?

Comment: Do you use Build validation in the PR?

Comment: to answer both comments: yes, we will use build validation. However an open PR could be siting there for a while, but the sequence in the build must aligned with the PR completion order - hence the "weird requirement" ;) the task is not trivial, I would not be asking if it was a matter of tooling or policies.